# I need to add Instagram follow button on my website where user can follow without redirecting the instagram website

Tags: javascript, button, instagram

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-59f4a28b67531349"></script>
```

This script redirect to the Instagram website. I don't want it to redirect to the website. Can anyone please solve the issue. User will follow instantly when user click the button.

Comment: Could you add some context? some code? What have you tried? Help us to help you.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-59f4a28b67531349"></script> I have this code which redirect to the instagram I want to follow instantly without redirecting.

Comment: Add the code to your question, please @Sifatuls.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-59f4a28b67531349"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't.

Instagram doesn't allow you to instantly follow someone with the push of a button from a different source.

If they did allow that, it could be very easily abused I.E a script that clicks the button automatically.

Comment: So there no way to do it without redirecting?